# AS3 - Removing the blinking cursor in text field

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor, textfield

Can I remove this blinking cursor from a textfield?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not in a INPUT Textfield.

You can still use some ticks with a Dynamic textfield which listens to KEY_UP events, but you'll have to do all the things by yourself (delete, home key, end key...), and you can forget about things like copy/paste, undo, mouse selection...

It's a tricky way. What can also work, is hide the textfield by setting its textcolor to the background color (so you won't see the cursor), or set its alpha to 0, then copy the text into another dynamic text field on KEY_UP events. Still, it's quite a hack.

Good luck.

Comment: is kind of tricky because am using it for a touch screen and the cursor follows key strokes so the cursor jsut stays at the beginning of the line.